# PHP Converting DATE+TIME+TIMEZONE to DATE+TIME+NEW-TIMEZONE PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this php output from client that returns

> Sat Apr 30 2022 19:23:03 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

I want that to convert in new timezone, the problem is I cannot control the data above sa I have to convert all of that  output into new timezone which is Brisbane Timezone

Like this

```
$current_date_time_timezone = "Sat Apr 30 2022 19:23:03 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
$timeBrisbane = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane');
$date_time_new_timezone = $date_time_new_timezone->setTimezone($timeBrisbane);
echo $date_time_new_timezone->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The output above returns error,

the output I want is like this:

output= `"Sat Apr 30 2022 19:23:03 GMT+10 (Australia/Brisbane)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse that initial string into a DateTime object.

Since the timezone offset is already there after "GMT" I’ll ignore the brackets part:

```
$current_date_time_timezone = "Sat Apr 30 2022 19:23:03 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)";
$timeBrisbane = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane');

$date_time_new_timezone = DateTime::createFromFormat("D M j Y H:i:s \G\M\TO+", $current_date_time_timezone);
$date_time_new_timezone->setTimezone($timeBrisbane);

echo $date_time_new_timezone->format("D M j Y H:i:s \G\M\TO \(e\)");
// Sat Apr 30 2022 21:23:03 GMT+1000 (Australia/Brisbane)
```